# iOS install tracking without Ad?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

We are using Google analytics and looking for a way to find how many users installed an app for a marketing campaign.

It's quite simple with android, you just append campaign parameters to the links that users would click.

It seems complex or impossible to do this in iOS unless I join ad-network or show advertisement in my app?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible without incorporating ads in your app. I have used the guidelines listed [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) to successfully track user interactions and events in iOS apps.

If you just need details on app installations, iTunesConnect's App Analytics might be sufficient.